# What resources will help me understand the fundamentals of Relational Database Design

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, rdbms-agnostic

This are few of the fundamental database questions which has always given me trouble. I have tried using google and wiki but I somehow I miss out on understanding the functionality rather than terminology.

If possible would really appreciate if someone can share more insights on this questions using some visual representative examples.

- What is a key? A candidate key? A
  primary key? An alternate key? A
  foreign key?
- What is an index and how does it help
  your database?
- What are the data types available and
  when to use which ones?

Comment: That's not a question, it's a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [Data Modeling for Information Professionals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130804509). You are asking about basic fundamental theory and concepts which are much better explained in a book than on a Q&A answer site like SO.

Answer (score 2):

Buy an introductory book about relational databases, such as one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018/best-book-for-a-new-database-developer).

Comment: I'm not a down-voter, but the only thing I can think of is that the books cited in the SO question tend to be 'practical' rather than explaining the fundamentals.  There should be a combination of the two sides of the game - theory and practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple search google or wiki...

[What is an index and how does it help your database?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29)

[What are the data types available and when to use which ones?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type)

But in every database (every version of the same db) You can have other data types...its better if You specify which type of db You are interesting

[A primary key](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-primary-key.html)

In this site You find other keys also ;)

Answer (score 0):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_key

There's not really much difference between a "primary key" and an "alternate key".  Searches by primary key might be more optimized.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29

Data types vary a lot between databases, but generally you'll have:

- Numeric data types like INTEGER and REAL.
- At least one string type like VARCHAR.
- Raw binary data (BLOB).
- NULL, to indicate the absence of a value.